Intermittent Layer Display Issue with GeoPackage Layers in QGIS 3.38.2 and 3.34.10 (LTR)
I am encountering an intermittent issue with the display of layers in QGIS, and I'm hoping to get some insight or solutions.
Problem description:
I’m working with QGIS 3.38.2, but I've also experienced this problem in the LTR version (3.34.10), which makes me think the issue isn’t specific to a particular version. The problem occurs when working with layers stored in a GeoPackage (.gpkg) database.
Issue details:
After a few minutes of navigating around the map (zooming, panning, etc.), one or more layers from the GeoPackage database suddenly disappear from the display. These layers are still visible in the Layers panel but are no longer rendered on the map canvas.
Steps taken so far:
Closing and reopening QGIS: Temporarily resolves the issue. The layers reappear when I reopen the project, but the issue eventually happens again.
Hardware acceleration: I tried enabling hardware acceleration under the QGIS options, but it had no effect on the issue.
Refreshing the map (F5): Unfortunately, this does not make the missing layers reappear.
Additional context:
The issue occurs intermittently, seemingly after a few minutes of normal map interaction.
The layers in question are all stored in a GeoPackage.
System specs: I am running QGIS on a Windows 11 machine with 32GB of RAM, an Intel i7 3.4GHz processor, and an Nvidia RTX A2000 GPU (drivers fully up-to-date). I don't believe this is a hardware issue given the system's specs.
There are no obvious error messages or logs that point to the root cause.
Has anyone experienced similar issues with layers disappearing after some map interaction?
Could this be related to a memory issue, rendering problem, or something specific to how QGIS handles GeoPackage files?

I have the same problem with layer stored in a network drive where the drive seem to regularly disconnect causing QGIS to loose access to the layer. (it's a network issue, not a QGIS one, layer stored locally are fine). If your layer are on a network drive try to work with a local copy to check if the problem is QGIS related or not

Thank you for your response! I hadn't considered the possibility of a network issue. The layers are indeed stored on a network drive, so I will definitely test with a local copy to see if that resolves the problem.
I'll report back with the results. Thanks again for the helpful suggestion!
